# How can i implement static folder path and get files to an array using this code

Tags: android

How can i implement direct folder path  to this code, this is an image viewer project with image reel slider Anybody Know the solution Please Help Me.
can someone help me

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Images {
    private int currentImage = 0;
    private List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getImagesSize() {
        return paths.size();
    }

    public String getImage(int index) {
        Log.i("Image", paths.get(index));
        return paths.get(index);
    }

    public void nextImageToDisplay() {
        if (currentImage >= paths.size() - 1) {
            currentImage = 0;
        } else {
            currentImage++;
        }
    }

    public void addImage(String path) {
        this.paths.add(path);
    }

    public String getCurrentImage() {
        return paths.get(currentImage);
    }

    public void setPathsToImages(List<String> paths) {
        this.paths = new ArrayList<>(paths);
    }

    public boolean contains(String imagePath) {
        return this.paths.contains(imagePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a 'direct folder path'?

Comment: Well what is exactly the problem! Adding a static variable?

Comment: i want to load images from a folder like /storage/images/ if i set path like this the i get all images from the folder to an array

Comment: Well ok. Please show how you want to set the path.. Also show code to put image paths from a folder in a list. And start explaining why you want that path to be static.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily.Suppose you want to get all files from /Pictures/Screenshots folder in sdcard.

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/Pictures/Screenshots");
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile()){
        String name = f.getName();
        System.out.println("name is :"+name);
        paths.add(name);
        }
    }
```